# The error about “Report all chuns to master with exception [RemoteRun[master]] Unrecognized column……”

Tags: cluster-computing, dolphindb

(1)There is a common cluster which contains machine A and B. The machine A is the controller node. Each machine owns one data node.

(2)After shutting down and upgrading the DolphinDB Server on machine A, the controller node, agent node and data node are restarted and the data node is normal.
The DolphinDB Server on machine B has not been upgraded. After I restart the agent node and data node, the data node cannot be initialized and an error is reported all the time:

```py
Report all chuns to master with exception [RemoteRun[master]] Unrecognized column……
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The current version (1.30.13, 2.0.1, 1.20.22) does not support rolling upgrades, so two physical machines A and B need to be shut down at the same time, then upgrade the DolphinDB Server on physical machines A and B, and then restart A and B The control node (Controller), agent node (Agent), and data node (Datanode) of the physical machine.

So the solution for the above situation:

(1) Shut down the entire cluster

(2) Complete DolphinDB Server of physical machine B

(3) Restart the control node (Controller), agent node (Agent), and data node (Datanode) of physical machines A and B

The subsequent version of DolphinDB will support rolling upgrades to avoid the occurrence of the above situation.